# Can't see new fields from PHP

Tags: php, php-toolkit

We're running a SOQL query in a PHP/Laravel app, using php-toolkit.  The query works fine, but we can't see new fields that we've added to our SF Org.

The fields show up if we do a "Salesforce::describeSObject('Account')", but we can't get data back from them when we run a query.  The SOQL query runs, but we can't access the field in the objects that come back.

We've triple-checked the spelling of the fields, and verified there are no field permission problems by pulling the data with the same account using the Data Loader.

If anyone could help us out, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't have any experience in the toolkit itself, but does your SOQL include the new fields those you added in the Org?

Comment: @jayant-das It turned out to be the WSDL file -- once we regenerated it, we could see the new fields.

Comment: Thanks for updating. You may like to add that as an answer so that this is considered resolved.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to solve the problem by regenerating a WSDL on the Salesforce web app, then updating that file in our PHP app.